# How to find 2 different string in php (string1 or string2)

Tags: php, html

```php
<form action="" method="post">
<?php if($input !== null){   //if input is submitted then show message
   if(strpos($input, '[key1]') === true or strpos($input, 'key2') === true) { //find the input [key1] or [key2] 
     echo " input contain [key1] or [key2] ";
   }else{ // input doesnt contain [key1] or [key2]
     echo " input didnt contain [key1] or [key2]";
   }
}else{ // showing form input
echo "
   <input type='text' name='inputText' maxlength='100' data-length=100 class='form-control char-textarea' rows='3' placeholder='use [key1] or [key2]' required aria-invalid='false'/>
   <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload' ><br>
   <button type='submit' name='SubmitButton' class='btn btn-primary mr-1 mb-1'>Send</button>
    ";
}?>
</form>
```

here the form i made, now how can i find if the input is contain [key1]`or`[key2] when they submit the form, i tried

```php
if(strpos($input, '[key1]') === true or strpos($input, 'key2') === true)
```

but the result is `echo " input didnt contain [key1] or [key2]";` and not `echo " input contain [key1] or [key2] ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos) returns either an integer (position if the string found) or `false` if the string is not found. So your test

```
if(strpos($input, '[key1]') === true or strpos($input, 'key2') === true)
```

will never pass, since an integer or `false` can never be `=== true`. Instead, change your test to check the result of `strpos` is not `false`:

```
if(strpos($input, '[key1]') !== false or strpos($input, 'key2') !== false)
```

Comment: wait, so how to find the string?

Comment: @TunkuSalim your question doesn't say anything about finding the string, only whether it exists or not

Comment: @mickmackusa it's not about the rep. It's about the satisfaction from helping people.

Comment: Please help people to find pre-existing answers.  Too late now, I see.